# Get a value from table with following command in sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to common values from a table by this command like

```
SELECT `variant_product_id` 
FROM `bshop_hikashop_variant` 
WHERE `variant_characteristic_id` = 212
```

and the second command is

```
SELECT `variant_product_id` 
FROM `bshop_hikashop_variant` 
WHERE `variant_characteristic_id` = 172
```

For this i have tried like this

```
SELECT `variant_product_id` 
FROM `bshop_hikashop_variant` 
WHERE `variant_characteristic_id` = 212 && `variant_characteristic_id` = 172
```

Which is not working. And also tried by this

```
SELECT `variant_product_id` 
FROM `bshop_hikashop_variant` 
WHERE `variant_characteristic_id` IN(212,172)
```

Which is also not working. Is there any simple command to get the common value ?

Let me show you the table

```
variant_characteristic_id       variant_product_id

212                             469                               
217                             486
222                             405
212                             411
172                             469
160                             411
212                             410
188                             444
200                             414
212                             410
172                             418
```

I want to get the 469 form "variant_product_id". Because it has match my condition. Means 212 has 469 and 172 has 469 also.

Please look the table to understand the condition.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The last query using `IN`, how is it not working? What do you mean by "not working"? It gives no result? Or it gives an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT variant_product_id
FROM bshop_hikashop_variant
WHERE variant_characteristic_id IN (212, 172)
GROUP BY variant_product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT variant_characteristic_id ) > 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d34f6/2)

Comment: @RanjitPradhan Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
create table table1
SELECT variant_product_id
FROM bshop_hikashop_variant
WHERE variant_characteristic_id=212 ;

create table table2
SELECT variant_product_id
FROM bshop_hikashop_variant
WHERE variant_characteristic_id=172 ;

SELECT table1.variant_product_id
FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.variant_product_id AND table2.variant_product_id
```